# Why can't you copy/paste images in excel, but screenshots work?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, screenshot

I'm not sure if this is a global issue with excel, but it's happening on all the computers here (Excel 2002, XP SP2)

If you select a cell, and go Ctrl-V when there's a screenshot in the clipboard, the image gets placed in the cell you've selected.

However, if you're got a copy/paste of something say from MS Paint, or any other image, if you do the same thing, the image goes directly to the top of the sheet.

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why that happens - it's something to do with the way Excel handles different objects

**Workaround:**

Go to **"Edit>Paste Special..."** and select **"Bitmap"** instead of **"Bitmap Image Object"**, it will paste correctly at your currently selected cell.

Comment: Oh I see.. it's a bit of long process, but I've created a AutoHotKey shortcut already (#v::send !es{Down}{Down}{Enter})

Comment: Sweet! AHK rocks. 

It seems like a bug to me, to be honest, but Microsoft will be Microsoft.

Comment: There is no option to do a paste special either.

Answer (score 1):

You might as well only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then the image appear on the top cell, however, without selecting that image (since it's already selected), just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for cutting, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in the same cell you actually wanted the image and it will appear there perfectly. This is the fastest way I found.